# Deep learning model test accuracy

Tags: deep-learning

100%|██████████| 161/161 [00:24<00:00,  6.46it/s]Test Loss: 0.0013
Test Accuracy of malware: 99% (3624/3642)
Test Accuracy of normal: 47% (701/1478)
Test Accuracy of 84% (4325/5120)

Deep learning model for binary malware classification (Malware vs Normal) is showing low overall test accuracy of 84%. However, the test accuracy of the malware samples is 99% but the normal is  accuracy 48% .
After running the model for 50 epochs

Comment: How much samples do you have of Malware vs Normal

Answer (score 0):

The cause for such results can be that you don't provide the model (during fitting) the same number (more or less) of samples from each category.